# Problems on web browser with xthml file

Tags: jsf, xhtml

I have a login.xhtml file as initial page in a jsf app.

The content of login.xtml is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
<title><ui:insert name="title">Spring-Security - Login</ui:insert>
</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<!-- Template CSS - Do not modify -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="# 
{facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}/css/classnotfound.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>
<div>
    <h:form id="loginFormId" prependId="false">
        <div class="forField" style="width: 65%">
            <h:inputText id="username" required="true"  requiredMessage="Please enter username (or go to hell...)" />
            <h:messages for="username" />
        </div>
    </h:form>
</div>
</h:body>
</html>
```

But when it loads in a web browser appears in console the message:

Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/xhtml+xml

without painting the h:form code
What is wrong?

Comment: Probably `# {facesContext.externalContext.request.contextPath}` is not being evaluated by jsf.

Comment: I've removed css include with a relative path and same occurs: Same console message and no painting of h:form code

Comment: What sort of web-server do you use?

Comment: Try creating resources/libraryname/css folder structure in your webapp folder, put your classnotfound.css file there. then declare it in your facelet using
<h:outputStylesheet name="css/classnotfound.css" library="libraryname" />